# PhoneGap- screen orientation not working for photo-gallery in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing a PhoneGap app. 
Screen orientation for all the pages working fine but when I open photo gallery in iPhone then it's screen orientation not supporting. Any solution will be appreciable.-Thanks

[image: here is screen-shot]

Comment: Please any one help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is an oversight in the default platform add script for phonegap / cordova that doesn't add the landscape orientations to the .xcodeproj file -- you'll need to add them yourself:

1. Under your project, browse down to the platforms / ios directory and double-click on the .xcodeproj to open it up in Xcode.
2. Select the project node in the left-hand column. In the center pane, look under Deployment Info / Device Orientation and make sure the Landscape orientations are selected.
3. Quit Xcode and rebuild / run emulate again. You should see the device respond to the rotate events.

I think this is only a bug on the iPhone. The iPad should already work correctly IIRC.

Comment: All the orientations is selected but not working.